# XMLs in C#, SimBrief XML

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to extract the name of fixes of a flight plan from an XML file but cannot seem to get it to work. The XML link can be found in the code. The XML snippet is not the whole file there are other nodes and elements.

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
namespace SBDataTest
{
    public class Program
    {


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            XmlDocument fplxml;

            XmlDocument fplxml = new XmlDocument();
            fplxml.LoadXml("https://www.simbrief.com/ofp/flightplans/xml/KEWRMMPR_XML_1520819500.xml");
            var str = fplsml.Parse(fplxml);

            var result = str.Elements("fix").
                            Where(x => x.Element("name")).ToList();

            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
}
```

XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OFP>
  <navlog>
    <fix>
      <ident>PARKE</ident>
      <name>PARKE</name>
      <type>wpt</type>
      <frequency/>
      <pos_lat>40.683183</pos_lat>
      <pos_long>-75.076478</pos_long>
      <stage>CLB</stage>
      <via_airway>DCT</via_airway>
      <is_sid_star>0</is_sid_star>
      <distance>57</distance>
    </fix>
    <fix>
        <ident>TOWIN</ident>
        <name>TOWIN</name>
        <type>wpt</type>
        <frequency/>
        <pos_lat>40.535211</pos_lat>
        <pos_long>-75.400378</pos_long>
        <stage>CLB</stage>
        <via_airway>J6</via_airway>
        <is_sid_star>0</is_sid_star>
        <distance>17</distance>
    </fix>
  </navlog>
</OFP>
```

Comment: Can you clarify the elements or attributes your trying to access? Also put a snipet of the xml in your question so people do not have to click some random url please .

Comment: xml url gives a 404

Comment: @SoftwareCarpenter just added

Comment: @shamanthGowdraShankaramurthy Just ignore that for now

Comment: What exactly is the issue you are finding ? At a guess I'd say its because "fix" is not an immediate child of the root element, but you are querying the Elements() of the Root

Comment: I get "the name Xelement does not exist in the current context" @PhillipH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Navlog(FILENAME); 
        }
    }
    public class Navlog
    {
        public static List<Navlog> logs { get; set; }

        public string ident { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public decimal? frequency { get; set; }
        public double latitude { get; set; }
        public double longitude { get; set; }
        public string stage { get; set; }
        public string airway { get; set; }
        public string star { get; set; }
        public int distance { get; set; }

        public Navlog() { }
        public Navlog(string filename)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filename);

            Navlog.logs = doc.Descendants("fix").Select(x => new Navlog()
            {
                ident = (string)x.Element("ident"),
                name = (string)x.Element("name"),
                type = (string)x.Element("type"),
                frequency = (string)x.Element("frequency") == "" ? null : (decimal?)x.Element("frequency"),
                latitude = (double)x.Element("pos_lat"),
                longitude = (double)x.Element("pos_long"),
                stage = (string)x.Element("stage"),
                airway = (string)x.Element("via_airway"),
                star = (string)x.Element("is_std_star"),
                distance = (int)x.Element("distance"),
            }).ToList();
        }

    }
}
```